# Is IP unnumbered still in wide use today?

Tags: ipv4, ip-address

I know the concept of IP unnumbered interfaces and that it was used to preserve IP addresses before VLSM came to be. I'm just curious to know if there are scenarios in current networks where IP unnumbered is/could be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Wide' is a bit broad to define.

Yes, it is still used for example in serial p2p interfaces, but maybe not to such an extent as in the past.

Scaling was the historical factor, however it is the implementation of the interface to have IP processing without a hardcoded IP address that allows still it's usefulness.

From Juniper on IPv6: "you can configure unnumbered interfaces to share the same subnet across multiple interfaces."

Perhaps 3 unspecific scenarios: overlapping subnets, wildcard interface for further processing, network design corner cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be great if you could elaborate the mentioned scenarios with an example. Especially wildcard interface and network design corner cases.

Answer (score 2):

Unnumbered certainly was helpful pre-VLSM but it's almost exclusively been adopted as a convenience - no need to allocate/configure individual IP's for point-to-point interfaces which means easier and/or less labor intensive provisioning.

It's definitely out there in certain places.  Smaller shops often use it because it's simple and, honestly, it shows up in a lot of basic configuration examples.  There's also been a bit of a resurgence in certain DevOps contexts as it reduces the number of touch points for turning up L3 connections.

Also - as has been the case since inception - it's also still frowned upon by plenty of engineers as it makes certain kinds of troubleshooting more difficult.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with those ones frowning, cause it would certainly make troubleshooting difficult!

Comment: I recall a talk on youtube from a major carrier (think it was a nanog talk) saying that IP unnumbered made it much easier to operate optical rings because you could add and remove devices from the ring without reconfiguring their neighbours. It also allowed the use of optical bypass switches to automatically reconnect the ring if a site went down.